# Why do datetime values from AD show up as 'System.__ComObject' in SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, active-directory, ldap

I am trying to create a package in SSIS that will read values from my AD and save into a table in a database.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM OpenQuery ( 
  ADSI,  
  'SELECT whenCreated,  whenChanged, [...], badPasswordTime, sAMAccountName
  FROM  ''LDAP://mydomain.com/OU=ouUsers,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=com'' 
  WHERE objectClass =  ''User'' AND displayName <> ''__Template__''
  ') AS tblADSI
ORDER BY sAMAccountName
```

asking for a lot of different attributes, I get datetime values for *whenChanged* and *whenCreated* (in the format `2018-01-01 00:00:00.000`), but tick values for all other datetime attributes - such as *badPasswordTime*, *lastLogon*, etc.

However, when I run basically the same query in SSIS (as an ADO.NET source, in one line):

```
<LDAP://mydomain.com/OU=ouUsers,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=com>;
(&(objectClass=user)(!displayName=__Template__));
sAMAccountName, badPasswordTime, [...]. whenChanged, whenCreated
```

When I click **Preview...** the values for the datetime attributes show up as *System.__ComObject* (except for *whenChanged* and *whenCreated*, like previously).

I can convert *whenChanged* and *whenCreated* values to DT_DATE just fine later in SSIS which is odd, because all these datetime attributes have the same format in AD (like `01/01/2018 00:00:00 GMT Standard Time`).

Can you advise how to get all these datetime attributes into DT_DATE?

Comment: whenChanged and whenCreated are described in the AD schema using the "Generalized Time" syntax. badPasswordTime and lastLogon are described with "Large Integer/Interval" syntax. Don't confuse what *some tool* is showing you as being contained in AD versus the actual AD schema.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I see now they appear as *INTEGER8* and not *GeneralizedTime* like I need to. But do you know how to get these attributes to show up as an integer and not *System.__ComObject* in SSIS?